# How to parametrize Select top 'n'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a stored procedure like this but I get an error

> Expecting '(', INTEGER, NUMERIC or REAL

This is my procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
    @numberOfRows int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP @numberOfRows *
    FROM dbo.myStoredProc   
END
```

Thank you!

Comment: Amazingly the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) explains exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **very** close - you just need to put the parameter value into brackets - like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProc]
    @numberOfRows int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (@numberOfRows) *
    FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere 
END
```

Also, you need to provide a valid **table name** for your `FROM` clause - you cannot select from the stored procedure you're just executing - that would be an endless loop in the making ....

See the [official MS documentation on `TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details

Comment: Thank you, it works.
PS. you are right about the table I am selecting from, I have made a mistake in transforming my stored procedure into a simpler example.

Comment: Note that `TOP` actually accepts a `bigint`